# How do I replace / remove only the numeric part in a alphanumeric string where only the number keeps changing using Notepad ++

Tags: regex, notepad++, alphanumeric

I have been trying to clean up some twitter streaming data which has got this error message in some places

```
    {"limit":{"track":1}}
    {"limit":{"track":26}}
    {"limit":{"track":34}}
```

I want them to be deleted with a space without disturbing the rest of the tweets.  since the numeric part keeps changing, removing them gets challenging. Searching for a solution here i have tried the following:

```
    {"limit":{"track":.*?}}
    {"limit":{"track":\d+}}
    {"limit":{"track":.*"\d+"}}
    "{"limit":{"track":".*?"}}"
```

and many other variations.  Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What's your expected output? use this regex `\d+`, and then replace the match with an empty string.

Comment: I want to delete the entire line....using find and replace helps me do it one by one...but my file has some 75000 lines and i have multiple files like that I have already tried applying \d+ as in my second option...doesnt seem to work

Comment: Thanks...but doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using regular expression `\{"limit"\:\{"track"\:\d+\}\}`?

Here is the settings screen:

[image]

`Replace with` has a space inside.

After clicking **Replace All**, all these strings will get replaced with a space.

Comment: I am trying to upvote your answer but since I am new to the site...guess I have to wait for somemore interaction to get those privileges.        Thank you so much again stribizhev

Comment: You can just click "Accepted" symbol right below the upvote. It is enough.